# How to find the angle when finger is swiped over an object in corona

Tags: android, iphone, lua, coronasdk

In my project if i drag on an object, a force is applied on an object and another object generates 
and move in the direction of the finger swipe and according to the amount of force applied, this code is working properly. But i want to rotate the second object that generates according to the angle of the finger swipe. I want to know how to get the angle of finger swipe and rotate the second object to that angle, Please give any suggestions. thanks...
Code for finger swipe is given below

```
local Objectswipe = display.newImage( "object1.png") 
Objectswipe.x = 100
Objectswipe.y = 200

target = display.newImage( "target.png" )    
target.x = Objectswipe.x; target.y = Objectswipe.y; target.alpha = 0

local function fingerswipe( event )
    local t = event.target

    local phase = event.phase
    if "began" == phase then
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( t )
        t.isFocus = true


        t:setLinearVelocity( 0, 0 )
        t.angularVelocity = 0

        target.x = t.x
        target.y = t.y

        startRotation = function()
            target.rotation = target.rotation + 4
        end

        Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", startRotation )

        local showTarget = transition.to( target, { alpha=0.4, xScale=0.4, yScale=0.4, time=200 } )
        myLine = nil

    elseif t.isFocus then
        if "moved" == phase then

            if ( myLine ) then
                myLine.parent:remove( myLine ) -- erase previous line, if any
            end
            myLine = display.newLine( t.x,t.y, event.x,event.y )
            myLine:setColor( 255, 255, 255, 50 )
            myLine.width = 8

        elseif "ended" == phase or "cancelled" == phase then
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
            t.isFocus = false

            local stopRotation = function()
                Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", startRotation )
            end

            local hideTarget = transition.to( target, { alpha=0, xScale=1.0, yScale=1.0, time=200, onComplete=stopRotation } )

            if ( myLine ) then
                myLine.parent:remove( myLine )
            end

            t:applyForce( (t.x - event.x), (t.y - event.y), t.x, t.y )

        end
    end

    return true
end

Objectswipe:addEventListener( "touch", fingerswipe )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this sample app that I've created. I use this function all the time.

```
local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()
physics.setGravity(0,0)
physics.setDrawMode("debug")


function getAngle(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    local PI = 3.14159265358
    local deltaY = y2 - y1
    local deltaX = x2 - x1

    local angleInDegrees = (((math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180)/ PI)+360)%360

    local mult = 10^0

    return math.floor(angleInDegrees * mult + 0.5) / mult
end

local c = display.newCircle(0,0,50)
c.x = display.contentWidth/2
c.y = display.contentHeight/2
physics.addBody(c,"dynamic",{radius = 50})


Runtime:addEventListener("touch",function(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then

    elseif event.phase == "moved" then
        local angle = getAngle(c.x,c.y,event.x,event.y)
        print(angle)
        c.rotation = angle
    elseif event.phase == "ended" then

    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do something like:

```
local point1 = {}
local point2 = {}

--save the coordinates for the ended phase
if event.phase == "ended" then
    point1.x = event.xStart
    point1.y = event.yStart

    point2.x = event.x
    point2.y = event.y
end

--arbitrary third point
point3 = {}
point3.x = point2.x
point3.y = point1.y
```

You would then have three points, and could calculate the angle. And you should be able to apply the force at the angle.

Comment: Can you please provide me a link of how to get the angle in corona or some example link. thanks for your above suggestions...

Comment: I updated the answer to simplify it using event.xStart and event.yStart. Look at this [link](http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/events-and-listeners#touch_single_touch) if you need some help with touch events.Try writing a custom function that takes three points as parameters and finds the angle between two of the sides.